# Maven Eclipse plugin - classpath entries for each?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

After running the maven Eclipse plugin, my .classpath includes all dependencies, like so:

```
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6-sources.jar"/>
```

Is there a way to get it to just include the maven classpath container, like so?

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of the Eclipse m2e plugin is that you don't have to worry about the Eclipse classpath - m2e automagically takes care of including dependencies listed in your pom.xml.
Voila!

In fact, it is recommended that you do *not* mess with the project classpath when using a pom.xml.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. It seems like the eclipse plugin might be deprecated, or at least should be?

Comment: No, the m2e plugin is alive and well and included with the latest eclipse downloads. You just have to activate it. Bottom line is it should make life simpler and easier - if it does not something is wrong!